# MySQL joins multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have 5 tables:

`comments(id, time, comment, sender, sender_type, user, milestone, time)`

`users(id, first_name)`

`representatives(id, first_name)`

`agents(id, first_name)`

`lawyers(id, first_name)`

There are 5 different milestones where the users, representative, agents and lawyers will comment. `The receiver is always the user` and the sender may be either and agent, lawyer or a representative.

I want to get results from the comments table for a given user(id) and milestone.

so for ex. in milestone 2 I want to get all the comments to user 1 from representatives and agents. I want to display the comment, the name of the sender, time, the user who received the comment and the comment.

This is my query but I get no results (0 rows)

```
$milestones = array(
   1 => ["representative"],
   2 => ["representative", "agent"],
   3 => ["representative"],
   4 => ["representative"],
   5 => ["representative", "lawyer"]
);

$allowed_types = '"' . implode('", "', $milestones[$milestone]) . '"';

$query = "
 select c.time, c.comment, u.first_name as user, r.first_name as represantive, l.first_name as lawyer, a.first_name as agent
 from comments c
    join users u
        on c.user = u.id
    left join representatives r
        on c.sender = r.id and c.sender_type = 'representative'
    left join lawyers l
       on c.sender = l.id and c.sender_type = 'lawyer'
    left join agents a
       on c.sender = a.id and c.sender_type = 'agent'
    where
        c.user = $user and c.sender_type in ($allowed_types)
 group by c.time
 order by time asc
 ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join instead:

```
select c.time, c.comment, u.first_name as user, r.first_name as represantive, l.first_name as lawyer, a.first_name as agent
from comments c
join users u
   on c.user = u.id
LEFT join representatives r
   on c.sender = r.id
LEFT join lawyers l
  on c.sender = l.id
LEFT join agents a
  on c.sender = a.id
where ...
```

Comment: its working but now I get too many fields for a comment, lawyer and a rep for ex. only one of them has sent the comment.

Comment: what is in your sender_type column? maybe you should filter using this information.. `left join table ... on sender = id AND c.sender_type = 'representatives'`

Comment: it is a string, either representative, lawyer or agent.

Comment: its working  thanks. How to hide the empty values. So if the sender is a lawyer I want to hide the empty field for agent and rep?

Comment: you can use coalesce: `COALESCE(r.first_name, l.first_name, a.first_name) as first_name`. It will return the first not null value from the list.

Comment: thanks, hey I have got another problem, I can not manage to display the comments that the user has sent, it working for comments sent to him but I can not display the comments the user has submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `left join` but with the right types:

```
Select ...
From users u join
     Comments c left join
     Representatives r
     On c.sender = r.id and c.type = 'representative' left join 
     ...
```

You need to include the type in the `on` clause for each join.

Comment: yeah I got it thanks, How to hide the empty values. So if the sender is a lawyer I want to hide the empty field for agent and rep?

Comment: @rexhin . . . That sounds like a different question.  You should ask it as a separate question with sample data and desired results.